# What does this C# class look like in F#

Tags: f#

I have this C# class `Project`:

```cs
public class Project
{
    private readonly IList _tasks = new List<>();
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartedTime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Project(ProjectStarted started)
    {
        Version = 1;
        Name = started.Name;
        StartedTime = started.Timestamp;
    }

    

    public void Apply(TaskRecorded recorded, IEvent e)
    {
        Version = e.Version;
        var task = new ProjectTask
        {
            Title = recorded.Title,
            Number = _tasks.Max(x => x.Number) + 1,
            Recorded = recorded.Timestamp
        };

        _tasks.Add(task);
    }

}

public class ProjectTask
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Recorded { get; set; }
}

public class TaskRecorded
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectStarted
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

How would this look like in F#?

I'm struggling to get the constructor right as well as the `Apply` method.

Update - That's what I've done so far:

```ml
type ProjectTask = {
  Title: string
  Number: int
  Recorded: DateTimeOffset
}

type TaskRecorded = {
  Title: string
  Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type ProjectStarted = {
  Name: string
  Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type Project(projectStarted) =
  member val Version = 1
  member val Name = projectStarted.Name
  member val StartedTime = projectStarted.Timestamp
  member this.Apply (recorded: TaskRecorded) (event: Events.IEvent) =
    Version <- event.Version
```

I'm trying to change the value of the Version property I've created in the constructor.

Update 2:

That's what I've done now:

```ml
type Project(projectStarted) =
  let mutable Version:int64 = int64(1)
  let mutable Tasks = []
  member val Name = projectStarted.Name
  member val StartedTime = projectStarted.Timestamp
  member this.Apply (recorded: TaskRecorded) (event: Events.IEvent) =
    Version <- event.Version
    let task = { Title=recorded.Title; Number= 1;Recorded = recorded.Timestamp  }
    Tasks = Tasks @ [task]
```

Not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Let's see what you've got so far.

Comment: Where is your incomplete F# solution?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but there's a couple changes to make it consistent with the C# code. using `let` makes the variable private when inside of the class's scope. You'll also need `with get, set` for the equivalent of the `{ get; set; }` in the C# code. Another thing to note is that `list` in F# is a linked list as opposed to C#'s `List` which is a resizable array, so typically you want to append to the front of a list instead of the back like you're doing in `Apply`. If you want to use the equivalent of C#'s `List`, you want `ResizeArray`. I left out the `Id` member since it isn't used anywhere. You'll also notice that to access the class's members (as opposed to a let-bound variable) you have to use the `this` that you named in `this.Apply`.

```ml
type Project(projectStarted) =
    let mutable tasks = []

    member val Version: int64 = 1L with get, set
    member val Name = projectStarted.Name with get, set
    member val StartedTime = projectStarted.Timestamp with get, set

    member this.Apply (recorded: TaskRecorded) (event: Events.IEvent) =
        this.Version <- event.Version

        let task =
            { Title = recorded.Title
              Number = 1
              Recorded = recorded.Timestamp }

        tasks <- tasks @ [ task ]
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I declare Id correctly? In my case it would have got it’s Value set from an external caller.

Comment: So there's a couple ways you could handle that, with I think the best way being to take the ID as an argument to the constructor if that's possible. Otherwise, you'll want to think about what representation ID will have before it's set. You could always use `null` like C# would, but using `null` in F# code isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this in the constructor: `member val Id = Guid.Empty with get,set`

Answer (score 1):

That's what I came up with - anyway looking for some comments if this is the correct way:

```ml
type ProjectTask = {
  Title: string
  Number: int
  Recorded: DateTimeOffset
}

type TaskRecorded = {
  Title: string
  Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type ProjectStarted = {
  Name: string
  Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}


type Project(projectStarted) =
  let mutable Version:int64 = int64(1)
  let mutable Tasks = []
  member val Name = projectStarted.Name
  member val StartedTime = projectStarted.Timestamp
  member this.Apply (recorded: TaskRecorded) (event: Events.IEvent) =
    Version <- event.Version
    let task = { Title=recorded.Title; Number= 1;Recorded = recorded.Timestamp  }
    Tasks = Tasks @ [task]
```